# Permission denied for relation (table name)company

Tags: postgresql, jsp

I am using Postgres and I am inserting a value:

```
stat.execute("insert into company(name,age,address,salary)values('"+s+"','24','dommanagdde','25000')");
```

It shows this error:

> permission denied for relation (table name)company

Can anyone help?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The account you use, has no permission to insert rows into `company` table. Talk to the admin of the database, or read about `GRANT` command to grant privileges to your account.

Answer (score 1):

The user you are using does not have `insert` permissions on the `company` table. You can solve this by granting them:

```
GRANT INSERT ON company TO someuser;
```

Answer (score 0):

[PostgreSQL GRANT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-grant/)

Radically via psql:

```
\c DB_NAME; - switch to your DB
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "public" TO someuser;
```